# SAML - how transfer custom attributes between Spring SAML extension(SP) and shibboleth 3.1.1(IDP)

Tags: java, spring, saml, shibboleth

I've implemented SSO using spring SAML(SP) & shibboleth 3.1.1(IDP) and I'm wondering is there any way to transfer custom attribute between the authRequest and authResponse.Lets say I want send my custom attribute(jobName) from sp to idp, idp verify the value, and then return this value to me.

I add md:Extensions md:RequestedAttribute saml:AttributeValue to my sp metadata file,and overide the getAuthnRequest method in WebSSOProfileImpl.java, But the generated authRequest don't contain the  in md:RequestedAttribute.

```
<md:Extensions xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
    <md:RequestedAttribute Name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3"
        NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri"
        isRequired="true"></md:RequestedAttribute>
</md:Extensions>

@Override
protected AuthnRequest getAuthnRequest(SAMLMessageContext context, WebSSOProfileOptions options, AssertionConsumerService assertionConsumer, SingleSignOnService bindingService) throws SAMLException, MetadataProviderException {
    AuthnRequest authnRequest = super.getAuthnRequest(context, options, assertionConsumer, bindingService);
    authnRequest.setExtensions(buildExtensions());
    authnRequest.setAttributeConsumingServiceIndex(1);
    return authnRequest;
}

protected Extensions buildExtensions() {

    Extensions extensions = new ExtensionsBuilder().buildObject();
    RequestedAttribute reqAttribute = new RequestedAttributeBuilder().buildObject();        

    reqAttribute.setName("urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3");
    reqAttribute.setNameFormat(AtomicRequestedAttribute.URI_REFERENCE);
    reqAttribute.setIsRequired(true);

    XSAny extraElement = new XSAnyBuilder().buildObject("saml:AttributeValue", "AttributeValue", "saml");
    extraElement.setTextContent("myjobName");

    reqAttribute.getAttributeValues().add(extraElement);

    extensions.getUnknownXMLObjects().add(reqAttribute);
    return extensions;

}

<md:AttributeConsumingService index="1">
    <md:ServiceName xml:lang="en">The Demo Test</md:ServiceName>
    <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="eduPersonScopedAffiliation" Name="urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.9" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" isRequired="true" >
        <saml2:AttributeValue>jobname1</saml2:AttributeValue>
        <saml2:AttributeValue>jobname2@</saml2:AttributeValue>
    </md:RequestedAttribute>
</md:AttributeConsumingService>
```

I dont have any clue how to go ahead with this? Should I've to modify my SP metada too with this additional attribute name and format? If yes, how should i do that? Any help in this regard would be really appreciated.

Thanks.
ltdong

Answer (score -2):

I'm not an expert with Spring Security SAML (not yet :-)), but I have the feeling that you may be coding too much and could achieve what you want by more XML configuration.

I know for sure that you can generate some extended metadata directly in your SP configuration by defining the property `extendedMetadata` in the class `MetadataGenerator`.

I have done this in my `applicationContext-security-saml.xml` file:

```xml
<!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata -->
<b:bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <b:constructor-arg>
        <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
            <b:property name="includeDiscoveryExtension" value="true"/>
            <b:property name="extendedMetadata">
                <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    <b:property name="SOME_PROPERTY" value="SOME_VALUE"/>
                    ...
                </b:bean>
            </b:property>
        </b:bean>
    </b:constructor-arg>
</b:bean>
```

Hopefully this helps a little.